# How to estimate parameters for a Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

In a previous question, I inquired about fitting distributions to some non-Gaussian empirical data.

It was suggested to me offline, that I might try the assumption that the data is Gaussian and fit a Kalman filter first.  Then, depending on the errors, decide if it is worth developing something fancier.  That makes sense.

So, with a nice set of time series data, I need to estimate **several** variable for a Kalman filter to run.

(Sure, there is probably an R package somewhere, but I want to actually **learn** how to do this myself.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Max Welling has a nice [tutorial](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/S.Prince/4C75/WellingKalmanFilter.pdf) that describes all of the Kalman Filtering and Smoothing equations as well as parameter estimation. This may be a good place to start.

Comment: Link is dead, here is an alternate https://web.archive.org/web/20120915073205/http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/S.Prince/4C75/LaceyThackerTutorial.pdf

Comment: I found the refered tutorial here https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3e9f/d115f7d13880d0aa515ee7ac45311c78f857.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is to use [Maximum Likelihood Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood). Basically, you need a Likelihood function and then run a standard optimizer (such as `optim`) to maximize your Likelihood.